# John Rennie, the nerd, crosses the 200k. Congratulations!

Tags: discussion, reputation

That's it! He did it!!

[John Rennie](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/1325/john-rennie), on 23-09-2016 became the first man ever in the realms of [Phys.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) to reach the summit of 200k!

For over five years, he travelled and saved people from the evils of confusion in almost every nook and corner of the kingdom of Physics.

And now he has crossed this landmark for the very first time in our community.

So, the community congratulates the beloved John Rennie for his magnificent  achievement.

[image]

*May the light of this old (handsome) nerd never be quelled* ;)

Comment: Congrats @JohnRennie.

Comment: Congratulations John, you must have a macro on your Pc that types "The universe did not begin at a point...."

Comment: The title would entertainingly suggest there are non-nerd Physics.SE users ;)

Comment: @cat: the site rules specifically ban non-nerds but rumour suggests some have sneaked in by concealing their status :-)

Comment: Congratulations John, personally i consider you as a guardian of Physics SE community.

Comment: Congrats and thanks

Comment: @user36790 Why are you calling him nerd?

Answer (score 48):

I would place a slightly different emphasis on this and instead highlight the progress of the Physics SE. A quick play with the Data Explorer tells me that between us the site members have written about 112,000 answers, and the average upvotes per answer is about 3.

This is an extraordinary achievement. Not only are we providing a huge number of answers to questions about physics, but we are providing a huge number of **useful** answers to questions about physics.

We all enjoy the neverending arguments about whether we have the balance of the site just right, whether we should be more or less lenient about homework questions, whether we're too aggressive with closing questions, and so on, and so on. But we shouldn't let our tendency to self criticism blind us to just how much has been achieved.

This is something of a hobby horse of mine, and apologies to everyone I have bored before on this subject, but as an enthusiastic physics nerd growing up in the UK in the 1970s it was inconceivable that I could ask questions of real live physicists. That todays young physicists can do this is quite remarkable and a testament to **everyone** who freely gives their time to make this site such a success.